# C# windows application

Tags: c#

Hi all  i am doing an application in win forms

I am having a small issue i.e i am having my main form as

Tree view, panel and a data grid. I am having some user control forms.

When i select a node from tree view corresponding user control will be get loaded in the panel if main form. This works good.

Now for the child nodes i am having some text files attached when i click on that i will display the data grid along with the data present in the text file. This also works fine.

But now when  click on data grid cells i would like to show the data in the user control form .

Can any one tell how to handle the controls from particular user controls that was displayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is to use event-handlers as a publisher-subscriber paradigm.
In your publisher you use `public event EventHandler FlightStarted;` and having a EventArgs class:

```
    public class StartEventArgs: EventArgs
    {
    public String flightCode { get; private set; }

    public StartEventArgs(String flightCode)
    {
        this.flightCode = flightCode;
    }
```

In your publisher class you use an OnSomething-method to fire off the event.

```
    public void OnFlightStarted(StartEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FlightStarted != null)
            FlightStarted(this, e);
    }
```

Now you need to have a subscriber as well:

```
flight.FlightStarted += new EventHandler(flight_FlightStarted);
```

and the method

```
    void flight_FlightLanded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (e is LandEventArgs)
        {
            LandEventArgs landEventArgs = e as LandEventArgs;
            String flight = landEventArgs.flightCode;
            while (flight.Length <= 15)
                flight += " ";
            String time = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            lbxStatus.Items.Insert(0, flight + "landed" 
                + "                 " + time);
        }
    }
```

More to read here: [Event Tutorial C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(VS.71).aspx)